# Sql Server Relation

Tags: sql

is any scientific reason to create a table with self join and 1 to many  relation in the same table >>> 
what i need is explain why we can't do this 
thanks for your time .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are perfectly valid situations that need such relations.

For example when you store a Tree on a table. Each node will have links to its childs (through a ParentId column), so it will have a relation 1 to many with itself.

Comment: that is true but in my case in my tree there is parent1 with his child as parent also to another child  but that child is content i but it in another table

Comment: for example table one have data like that
id=1 title=title1 as tree parent with parent id=0
new row in the same table
id=2 title=title1 with parent id=1
in second table there is content with relation 1 to many
like id=1 title=content title1 parentid=2
id=1 title=content title1 parentid=2

Comment: for example table one have data like that
id=1 title=title1 as tree parent with parent id=0
new row in the same table
id=2 title=title1 with parent id=1
in second table there is content with relation 1 to many
like id=1 title=content title1 parentid=2
id=1 title=content title2 parentid=2

but content have new columns like rate,views ,image and video
that why i create new table with new attributes 

my senior what to but all this in one table with all  attributes  in 2 tale will be  in one table and many null columns will be in new table 
is that true????

Comment: Yes, I would also put everything on the same table. I see no reason to split the information within two different tables. You will have a relation 1 to 1 between your nodes table and your content table, and tables with 1 to 1 relations can be fused into a single table.